# Live stream video with FMS 4.5 to iPhone/iPad packaged with Flash Builder

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, flash-builder, flash-media-server, http-live-streaming

They say that we can stream live video with FMS 4.5 to iPhone/iPad. I'm completely lost in Adobe announcements and bloggers reposts.

Is there real sample or article about how to make live video stream on iPhone/iPad possible. I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 to develop applications.

Goal is simple: one user broadcasts stream from pc. Other users playback from iOS. Application is build by Flash Builder.

Stan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/video_content_tv.html

Answer (score 2):

Adobe [announcement](http://blogs.adobe.com/ktowes/2011/04/sneak-peak-future-adobe-technology-for-http-streaming-across-multiple-devices.html) said that streaming implemented for iOS devices with HTML5. You can **NOT** stream to application that are built with Flash Builder